# How to add text inside the WooCommerce review order table without a hook

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, html-table, checkout

I want to add some text inside the checkout Woocommerce review order table ( before the cart items), inside the `review-order.php` template file.

I want to add it directly inside the template, NOT by using a hook!

The problem is that even if I add the text after the opening `<table>` tag, it gets displayed ABOVE the table when I check the page's html, but I need it inside the table. So

```php
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
<tbody>
<p>...</p>
</tbody>
</table>
```

does not work.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/review-order.php
>
> - This template can be overridden by copying it to **`yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php`**.

You have to wrap it in [`<table>`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) tags

```php
<tr><td>My text</td></tr>
```

So you get:

```php
<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>My text</td></tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```